# How to get the client domain info from kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I run nginx on pod in Kubernetes, and I want to do proxy_pass in nginx according to the client request domain something like a.b.c . but I got the service name.

So how to get the client domain info from Kubernetes pod?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you're asking for the HTTP "Host" header, right?  Kubernetes does not touch that at all.  Can you maybe explain more about what you mean with "I got the service name"?   Where did you get that?

Comment: I use ingress controller. I got `proxy_pass http://my-nginx-svc` in ingress-nginx, and I got the Host of each request in header is `my-nginx-svc`. I got the correct "Host" header  if I set `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in nginx.conf which is in ingress controller.

Comment: You are correct, by default ingress-nginx will not pass the the Host header. The template uses the nginx default values. Please check the code for the template that generates the configuration https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/Ingress/controllers/nginx-alpha/controller.go#L34

Comment: @sope https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/pull/305 is merged. Please build a new image for nginx-alpha.